# PrimeFaces does not render

Tags: jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces does not render even though it renders another example code (I borrowed this code from PrimeFaces website).

```
<ui:fragment xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">


<div style="height:500px">
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

        <p:dashboard id="board" model="#{dashboardView.model}">
            <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{dashboardView.handleReorder}" update="msgs" />

            <p:panel id="sports" header="Sports">
                <h:outputText value="Sports Content" />
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel id="finance" header="Finance">
                <h:outputText value="Finance Content" />
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel id="lifestyle" header="Lifestyle">
                <h:outputText value="Lifestyle Content"  />
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel id="weather" header="Weather">
                <h:outputText value="Weather Content" />
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel id="politics" header="Politics">
                <h:outputText value="Politics Content" />
            </p:panel>
        </p:dashboard>

        <div style="clear:both" />
    </h:form>
</div>
</ui:fragment>
```

Here is .java part of it: 
I need to use such a drag drop dashboards, if you cant figure out the problem please recommend me another js that I can do it but with examples.

```
package tr.com.solveka.plantmet.web.station;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.CloseEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.DashboardReorderEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.ToggleEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DashboardColumn;
import org.primefaces.model.DashboardModel;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultDashboardColumn;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultDashboardModel;
@ManagedBean(name="DashboardView")
@ViewScoped
public class DashboardView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DashboardModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        model = new DefaultDashboardModel();
        DashboardColumn column1 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
        DashboardColumn column2 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
        DashboardColumn column3 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();

        column1.addWidget("sports");
        column1.addWidget("finance");

        column2.addWidget("lifestyle");
        column2.addWidget("weather");

        column3.addWidget("politics");

        model.addColumn(column1);
        model.addColumn(column2);
        model.addColumn(column3);
    }

    public void handleReorder(DashboardReorderEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        message.setSummary("Reordered: " + event.getWidgetId());
        message.setDetail("Item index: " + event.getItemIndex() + ", Column index: " + event.getColumnIndex() + ", Sender index: " + event.getSenderColumnIndex());

        addMessage(message);
    }

    public void handleClose(CloseEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Panel Closed", "Closed panel id:'" + event.getComponent().getId() + "'");

        addMessage(message);
    }

    public void handleToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, event.getComponent().getId() + " toggled", "Status:" + event.getVisibility().name());

        addMessage(message);
    }

    private void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    public DashboardModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not run `ui:fragment` without using `html` frame or template.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <!--here your code-->
        <div style="height:500px">
            <h:form>
                .....
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

[How to use JSF Teampalte?](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/)